# namespace custom conventions - views and view models are in separated assembly

Tags: c#, namespaces, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I have ShellView and ShellViewModel in single assembly named MyApp.Shell.

ViewModel:

```
namespace MyApp.Shell.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.AllActive, IShellViewModel
    {
        public IMenuViewModel Menu { get; set; }

    }
}
```

View:

```
namespace MyApp.Shell.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ShellView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ShellView : Window
    {
        public ShellView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

In another assembly named MyApp.MenuViewModel I have part MenuViewModel.

```
namespace MyApp.MenuViewModel.ViewModels
{
    public class MenuViewModel : Screen, IMenuViewModel
    {

    }
}
```

And in third assembly named MyApp.MenuView I have part MenuView.

```
namespace MyApp.MenuView.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MenuView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MenuView : UserControl
    {
        public MenuView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I want load MenuView from assembly MyApp.MenuView in ShellView.

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Shell.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ShellView" Height="600" Width="1000">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowMenu" Height="25"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <ContentControl x:Name="Menu" Grid.Row="0"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Because namespace are not same I tried map namespaces in method Configure in bootstraper:

My goal is translate namespace MyApp.MenuView.Views -> MyApp.Shell.Views

```
 ViewLocator.AddSubNamespaceMapping("MyApp.*.Views", "Shell");
```

and translate namespace MyApp.MenuViewModel.ViewModels -> MyApp.Shell.ViewModels

```
ViewModelLocator.AddSubNamespaceMapping("MyApp.*.ViewModels", "Shell");
```

but when I run app I got error:

Can not find view for MyApp.MenuViewModel.ViewModels. MenuViewModel

Also I tried this

```
        ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("MyApp.*.Views", "MyApp.Shell.Views");

        ViewModelLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("MyApp.*.ViewModels", "MyApp.Shell.ViewModels");
```

What is wrong ? Problem is in AddSubNamespaceMapping / AddNamespaceMapping method or root of this problem is some another place?

Because if I change namespace MyApp.MenuView.Views to MyApp.Shell.Views in assembly MyApp.MenuView everything is OK.

Thank you

**HERE IS BOOTSTRAPPER:**

Maybe I use  AddSubNamespaceMapping on wrong place.

```
public class CWBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShellViewModel>
    {
        #region Fields

        private IWindsorContainer _container;

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private IEnumerable<Assembly> LoadAssemblies(string folder)
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file.FullName);
                Assembly assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyName);//Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
                yield return assembly;
            }

            yield break;
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer();

            _container.Register(Component
                                .For<IWindowManager>()
                                .ImplementedBy<WindowManager>()
                                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton));

            _container.Register(Component
                                .For<IEventAggregator>()
                                .ImplementedBy<EventAggregator>()
                                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton));


            _container.Install(new ViewModelsInstaller());
            _container.Install(new ViewsInstaller());


            //MyApp.MenuView.Views
            ViewLocator.AddSubNamespaceMapping("MyApp.*.Views", "Shell");
            //MyApp.MenuViewModel.ViewModels
            ViewModelLocator.AddSubNamespaceMapping("MyApp.*.ViewModels", "Shell");

            var config = new TypeMappingConfiguration
            {

                DefaultSubNamespaceForViews = "MyApp.Shell.Views",
                DefaultSubNamespaceForViewModels = "MyApp.Shell.ViewModels",

                ViewModelSuffix = "ViewModel",
                ViewSuffixList = new List<string> { "View" }
            };

            ViewLocator.ConfigureTypeMappings(config);
            ViewModelLocator.ConfigureTypeMappings(config);

        }


        protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
        {
            var assemblies = base.SelectAssemblies().ToList();

    //load views asm from folder Views
            IEnumerable<Assembly> viewsAsm = LoadAssemblies(@"Views");
    //load viewmodels asm from folder ViewModel
            IEnumerable<Assembly> viewModelsAsm = LoadAssemblies(@"ViewModels");

            assemblies.AddRange(viewsAsm);
            assemblies.AddRange(viewModelsAsm);

            return assemblies;
        }

        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key)
                       ? _container.Resolve(service)
                       : _container.Resolve(key, new { });
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(service).Cast<object>();
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            instance.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(property => property.CanWrite && property.PropertyType.IsPublic)
                .Where(property => _container.Kernel.HasComponent(property.PropertyType))
                .ForEach(property => property.SetValue(instance, _container.Resolve(property.PropertyType), null));
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**EDITED:**

I upload my solution here: http://www.4shared.com/rar/yaPwUV6d/App.html

Coudl anybody help me. I can not find what is wrong.

Comment: Have you added the `MyApp.MenuView` assembly to the `AssemblySource.Instance` collection in the bootstrapper ?

Comment: @Sniffer: I load all assemblies for views and viewmodels. I added my boostrapper class to original post. Maybe I use method AddSubNamespaceMapping on wrong place in boostraper class.

Comment: If you could upload a sample of the project *(if possible)* to [4shared.com](http://www.4shared.com) i would look into it and see what is wrong.

Comment: @Sniffer. Here is link http://www.4shared.com/rar/yaPwUV6d/App.html  I'm a little clueles. You might find what's wrong. Thank you for help and your time.

Comment: Ahh, i forget to say that i have visual studio 2010 and windows XP. Sorry for that. I will try to figure out the problem by reading your question again.

Comment: @Sniffer: oops, I tried convert vs 212 sln and projects to vs 2010, but without success. Thank

Comment: Are you doing view-first or view-model first navigation ?

Comment: @Sniffer: Look at my ShellViewModel, and ShellView class I am not sure but in my opinion  view model first navigation.  If I change namespaces in MyApp.MenuViewModel asm to MyApp.Shell.ViewModels and im asm MyApp.MenuView asm to MyApp.Shell.Views it works good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Kopernik, your question got me reading a lot of the information i was putting on hold. Nevertheless, your problem can be fixed with one line of code:

```
ViewLocator.AddSubNamespaceMapping("MyApp.MenuViewModel.ViewModels", "MyApp.MenuView.Views");
```

If this doesn't work alone then **please** make sure you are adding/loading the assemblies containing the views *(in your situation that is `MyApp.MenuView`)* to `AssemblySource.Instance` correctly in your `SelectAssemblies()` override.

The basic idea behind your problem is that Caliburn.Micro's `ViewLocator` was looking for either `MyApp.MenuViewModel.ViewModels.MenuView` or `MyApp.MenuViewModel.Views.MenuView` and it couldn't find any of them.

Essentially what i did is told Caliburn.Micro's `ViewLocator` to substitute `MyApp.MenuViewModel.ViewModels` with `MyApp.MenuView.Views` when it wanted to search for the view and wallah! it found it.

From what i was able to figure out from your code, it looks like you are doing view-model first navigation so you won't need anything else for the moment.

One last thing, a thorough explanation of the problem and how to fix it may require a lot of explaining which i really don't have time for so i suggest you read the [NameTransformer](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20NameTransformer&referringTitle=Documentation) and [ViewModel/View Naming Conventions](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View/ViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation) articles to get a very good idea about this.

Comment: Thank, it works. It’s understandable for me. I have one additional question. I define caliburn replace all "view models namespace" with namespace MyApp.Views:           ViewLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("MyApp.*.ViewModels", "MyApp.Views"); and also replace all "views namespaces" with namespace MyApp.Views:             ViewModelLocator.AddNamespaceMapping("MyApp.*.Views", "MyApp.Views");. This way doesnt work. I hope that now I will have all views and view models in same namespace MyApp.Views. Could you explain it. Thank you for help. I help me a lot.

Comment: @Kopernik i don't exactly know why this isn't working because this requires a deep look into the source code and Caliburn.Micro's documentation doesn't talk about these methods a lot but i think the problem might be with the `*` symbol, how Caliburn.Micro should interpret that because the method parameters doesn't accept a regular expression. As i have said have a look at the documentation links i gave you and if you want a very close look check the source. One final thing, please accept the answer and an uptick would be great because it took me some effort and reading time to get this.